# ValueError: volume and kernel should have the same dimensionality

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to find peaks of an audio signal and have written the following code

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks_cwt
import numpy as np




input_data = read("clip_norm.wav")
audio = input_data[1]
peaks = find_peaks_cwt(audio, widths=np.arange(1,4), max_distances=np.arange(1, 4)*2)
peaks = np.array(peaks) - 1

print('Peaks are: %s' % (peaks))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: volume and kernel should have the same dimensionality
```

I would appreciate any assistance. Maybe there is a better way of getting the peaks of audio. I would like to store the time/samples location in a one dimensional array.